# Does this count as "data leakage"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to tune my k-Nearest Neighbours model with Grid Search. But because my data set is wonky, I need to standardize it first.

However, I have read in a tutorial that Standardizing before doing k-fold cross validation leads to data leakage, because the validation set influences the training set.

I want to ask if this problem exists in my code block below. And if so, how I can avoid this. Thank you!

```
#Standardizing my data

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
rescaledX = scaler.transform(X_train)

#Using Grid Search and k-fold cross validation

k_values = numpy.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21])
param_grid = dict(n_neighbors=k_values)
model = KNeighborsRegressor()
kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, random_state=seed, shuffle=True)

#Does this step cause data leakage if all folds in k-fold were standardized together in 2nd line?

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scoring, cv=kfold)
grid_result = grid.fit(rescaledX, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is data leakage**: the scoring in the grid search is from test folds, but those were all scaled together with the rest of `X_train`, so some information from the test fold has been "seen" by the models.

You can fix this using sklearn Pipelines, to do the scaling and the model fitting on the training folds of the grid search only:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scale', StandardScaler()),
                       ('knn', KNeighborsRegressor())])
# the hyperparameter names need a prefix now that the model is in a pipeline:
param_grid = dict(knn__n_neighbors=k_values)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scoring, cv=kfold)
grid_result = grid.fit(rescaledX, Y_train)
```

(Now, data leakage from scaling may be a fairly mild version, especially if your training set is actually a good representative sample.  And since the scores being affected are just those used to select hyperparameters (note that the `best_score_` is not an unbiased estimate!), any leakage would have to have the effect of benefiting some hyperparameter over another.
But in this case, **just use the pipeline**: it probably won't hurt computation time substantially, it's more statistically rigorous, and it's easier to test and put into production (with the scaling step built-in for unseen data).)